Finding an observer fitted for a ramp
According to control theory, an optimal observer for a linear process with random noise is the discrete Kalman filter:
$$\hat{x}_{k+1|k}=F_k \hat{x}_k + G_k u_k$$
$$P_{k+1|k}=F^t_k P_{k} F_k + Q_k$$
$$S_k=H^t_k P_{k+1|k} H_k+R_k$$
$$K_k=P_{k+1|k}H^t_k S^{-1}_k$$
$$\hat{x}_{k+1}=\hat{x}_{k+1|k}+K_k (y_k-H_k \hat{x}_{k+1|k})$$
$$P_{k+1}=(I-H_k K_k) P_{k+1|k}$$
Now for a stationary ramp process:
$$x_{k+1}=x_{k}+a.dt+v_k$$
The output and slope can be estimated by:
$$\hat{x}_{k+1}=\hat{x}_{k}+\hat{a}_k.dt+ K1_k(x_{k+1}-\hat{a}_k.dt-\hat{x}_{k})$$
$$\hat{a}_{k+1}=\hat{a}_{k}+K2_k(x_{k+1}-\hat{a}_k.dt-\hat{x}_{k})$$
I have found on a site that the optimal gain are
$$K1_k=\frac{2(2k-1)}{k(k*1)}$$
$$K2_k=\frac{6}{k(k+1).dt}$$
I would not expect a proof for it, since I tested it successfully within a program. Instead I would be interested by this formula for the standard deviation:
$$E((x_k-\hat{x}_k)^2)=\frac{2(2k-1)}{k(k+1)}\sigma^2_n$$
Many thanks

"I have found on a site".  Please edit your question with a citation of your site.  They're making assumptions that won't be true for all cases.

Your equation to $\hat x_{k+1}$ leaves out the $v_k$ term -- is this intentional?


According to control theory, an optimal observer for a linear process with random noise is the discrete Kalman filter

A Kalman filter is an optimal observer for a linear process when the noise is random, stationary, and Gaussian, when the cost function is quadratic in the states, and when the underlying system model used to construct the filter matches the real system exactly.
It misses optimality to varying degrees of horribleness when these conditions are not met.

I'm not sure what your source is doing, but you're not giving the full system model.  If you want to get the answer you're looking for, you need the full system model*:
$$\mathbf x_{k} = \mathbf F \mathbf x_{k-1} + \mathbf G \mathbf u_k + \mathbf w_k \tag 1$$
$$\mathbf y_k = \mathbf H \mathbf x_k + \mathbf r_k \tag 2$$
In your case it looks like you're using not quite right equations for the state evolution.  Assuming that $\mathbf x_k = \begin{bmatrix}
x_k & v_k & a_k \end{bmatrix}$ and that your $dt$ is the sampling interval, then you should use
$$\mathbf F = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & dt & \frac{(dt)^2}{2} \\
0 & 1 & dt \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \tag 3$$
At any rate, the values of the $\mathbf P$ and $\mathbf K$ matrices will depend on the values of $\mathbf F$, $\mathbf G$, $\mathbf H$, $\mathbf w$, and $\mathbf r$; only $\mathbf F$ is given, and it seems to be incorrect. You need to verify $\mathbf F$, and find the values for the others that match your physical system.
If these arrays remain constant over time, then you can find the steady state values for the gain ($\mathbf K$) and covariance ($\mathbf P$) matrices.  It's pretty easy to pluck out the variance of the elements of $\mathbf x_k$ from $\mathbf P$.

* I'm using the common notation found on Wikipedia.
